# Javascript - Google Maps - Autofill

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a form that I am putting together and I am trying to have it auto fill my fields. I have been successful with 95% of it, however, I am having difficulty getting the Lat / Long cords to auto fill into the appropriate form field.

Here is my HTML

```
            <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address *</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input value="" placeholder="Enter the customers full address" class="form-control" id="autocomplete" type="text">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">House Number</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input value="" class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="true">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Street Address</label>
                <div class="controls">                
                    <input value="" class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">City</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input value="" class="form-control" id="locality" disabled="true">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">State</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input value="" class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
                </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Zipcode</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input value="" class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input value="" class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">  
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Lat</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input value="" class="form-control" id="LatLngBounds" disabled="true">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Long</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input value="" class="form-control" id="LatLngBounds" disabled="true">
                </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my Javascript.

```
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
// Need to add Lat / Long to populate field.
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name',

    };

function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')),{ types: ['geocode']});
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

    function fillInAddress() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            for (var component in componentForm) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = "";
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = true;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  You have two elements with id="LatLngBounds". How did you try to populate that element?

Comment: I know I had put that there, and was hoping that it would auto fill both fields. This was as an attempt to get it to work, but it didnt. I just copied what I had at the time straight to the question. @geocodezip

Comment: indeed the demo from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform did not propagate lat lng. To get the Lat Lng  pair you need to add parsing the PlaceResult.geometry object: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult

Comment: It is the demo. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. your HTML is invalid.  You have two elements with id="LatLngBounds".
2. you don't have any code to populate the latitude and longitude values in the form.

Fixing those makes it work for me:

**code snippet:**

```js
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
     // Need to add Lat / Long to populate field.
    var componentForm = {
      street_number: 'short_name',
      route: 'long_name',
      locality: 'long_name',
      administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
      country: 'long_name',
      postal_code: 'short_name',

    };

    function initAutocomplete() {
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
      });
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = "";
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = true;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
          var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
          document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("Latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
      document.getElementById("Longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initAutocomplete);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Address *</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="Beacon St, Boston, MA" placeholder="Enter the customers full address" class="form-control" id="autocomplete" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">House Number</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="" class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="true">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Street Address</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="" class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">City</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="" class="form-control" id="locality" disabled="true">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">State</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="" class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Zipcode</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="" class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Country</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="" class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Lat</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="" class="form-control" id="Latitude" disabled="true">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Long</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input value="" class="form-control" id="Longitude" disabled="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. I really appreciate it! I am now having difficulty passing the variables that it places within the input field through PHP/Sql. Why would my form be posting blank values?